# How can I stop nauseous animals from vomiting everywhere?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a rather...unpleasant problem in Dwarf Fortress. Currently, over half of my animals are "Nauseous" and are...regurgitating everywhere. This widespread case of emesis doesn't seem to involve my dwarves who I've been protecting against cave adaptation pretty well due to the lack of goblin ambushes. Does anyone know how this might have started or how to fix it?

Is it just that Fluffy was weak-stomached when Urist McBruisedguts came to the hospital after a battle that lead to a domino effect of animals being grossed out? Is it some seasonal animal flu? They're walking around fine, just leaving green trails...all over my food stockpiles, hospital, barracks, above-ground farms, workshops, mega-pile, and everywhere else...

Should I lock them all in a room and send in the Hazmat team after/if it passes? Should I have an animal genocide and hope Urist McAxelord doesn't go berserk? Should I just assign all my dwarves to just cleaning to try to stop the possible domino effect going on?

EDIT: 49 out of 106 animals are nauseous. Here's a screen shot of my dining room/kitchen/food stockpiles/bedrooms to help you realize the severity of this problem: [Linky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzdJo.png) (Yes, I know it doesn't actually affect gameplay any.)

Comment: This game sounds very strange.

Comment: Yes, it can be very strange indeed.

Comment: Too many more of these odd questions will lead me to playing this infernal game...

Comment: Had any forgotten beasts lately?

Comment: A couple. The last one was a slate serpent with that crazy dust that killed a dog and farmer before slamming itself into a stone wall and splitting in two.

Comment: I have this same problem with mysterious pools of blood. I'm worried my dwarves are about to go Carrie.

Comment: I know Dwarf Fortress is a bit like staring into the Matrix, but dang if that screenshot didn't remind me of when old DOS programs would freak out and write random bits into the text mode address range.

Comment: @ZoogieZork: there exists a tile set specifically designed to make it look *more* like the Matrix.

Comment: @JavadocMD If you get psychotic psychic dwarves I want to know about it.

Comment: @jblaske, I just remarked to my colleagues about these strange questions, and we all decided to just start and play it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to fix it (i.e., remove all the piles of vomit) you can download DFHack and use the "clean" subprogram to remove all contaminants on the map. Works on blood, dye, snow, vomit, and ichor, I think.

If you do that and your animals remain nauseous, you might have some underlying cause.

Comment: Would that also work on mud? Because I have a couple underground farms and I harvest trees down there...

Comment: DFHack's clean fucntion EXPLICITLY preserves mud.

Comment: k, download's done, I'll try it.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Thanks for the hack/fix, but do you know why this is necessary? Why are our dwarves not cleaning things like this automatically?

Comment: Nowai! That actually worked! All but one stopped being nauseous once there weren't piles of vomit everywhere! Thanks!

Comment: @JavadocMD is it a lack of soap? As to *why* it happens any liquid contaminants have the unfortunate ability to multiply when pathed over repeatedly, I don't know the exact mechanics but it happens.

Comment: Everything was cured of it for about a month, but all the animals are throwing up all over again. I'm trying to clean the map repeatedly, but it isn't helping now...

Comment: @Ullallulloo Have you ever read "Old Yeller"? [spoiler]

Answer (score 6):

I asked it on the bay12 forums [here](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=65738.0). I think Sphalerite was right about it being that FB's dust. (I can see Raven was thinking something like that too.) Every one of the nauseous animals just suffocated, almost simultaneously...I hope I can build 50 coffins fast, and keep a mega tantrum spiral from happening. O.O

EDIT: Oh, no it's starting! My legendary dining room better work it's magic!

Comment: Ha. "Had any forgotten beasts lately?" indeed. You're lucky it was only the animals!

Comment: I've never heard of FB dust targetted specifically on animals. If we could narrow it down to (female) cats, this could open up whole new avenues in biological warfare^W pet management.

Comment: @yatima2975 indeed, my first thought was "symptoms", but I have never heard of symptoms being discriminate about their targets. Perhaps it's a contact poison and Ulla is one of those few players that don't let his dwarves go stark naked.

Comment: @kotezkot That might have had something to do with it. I think it's mostly that adult dwarves have a strong enough immune system to deal with it.